# UIActivityIndicatorView not appearing in Subview

Tags: ios

So previously in my application, I had an **UIActivityIndicatorView** for processes that let the User know that something is loading. I wanted to add a layer of text to inform the user such as signing up,retrieving data, etc.  I created a UIView, set it's frame to be in the center of the screen, than my hope was to create the **UIActivityIndicatorView** in the center and the UILabel in the bottom fourth.  My label appears as planned, however now my **UIActivityIndicatorView** does not appear anymore so I'm curious to as why.  I have made sure that the **UIActivityIndicatorView** is white so it's visible against the  black background color and checked other common pitfalls.  It seems I'm not understanding something and I was curious if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks

```
/*Create the UIView that will serve as the frame to our label and activity view*/
UIView *indicatorFrame=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-50, (self.view.frame.size.height-self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height-self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height)/2.0-50, 100, 100)];
indicatorFrame.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
indicatorFrame.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
indicatorFrame.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
indicatorFrame.layer.cornerRadius=10.0f;
indicatorFrame.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
[self.view addSubview:indicatorFrame];


/*Create activity indicator*/
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(indicatorFrame.frame.size.width/2.0,indicatorFrame.frame
                               .size.height/2)];
[indicatorFrame addSubview:spinner];

/*Create Text Label to be added to the indicatorFrame*/
UILabel *indicatorViewText=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,indicatorFrame.frame.size.height/2,indicatorFrame.frame.size.width-5,30)];
[indicatorViewText setCenter:CGPointMake(indicatorFrame.frame.size.width/2,(indicatorFrame.frame.size.height)*3/4)];
indicatorViewText.text=@"Logging In";
indicatorViewText.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:18];
indicatorViewText.numberOfLines=1;
indicatorViewText.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
indicatorViewText.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
indicatorViewText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
[indicatorFrame addSubview:indicatorViewText];

[spinner startAnimating];
```

Comment: try to set the frame of the UIActivityIndicatorView

Comment: I tried that previously and nothing appeared still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried your code and it works without a problem. Your problem could be somewhere else in the rest of your view controller.

Your codes' output https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P73u.png

[image: Your codes' output]

However, the only change i did is to make the text visible by settings its background color to clear color.

My personal opinion however, is to use a library like MBProgressHUD or JGProgressHUD. They cut down your code drastically and you do not have to worry about these kind of problems.

Comment: thanks, I'll definitely take a look at those libraries.  I figured it out.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. If you can share your solution, it might be helpful to others; is'nt that what stackoverflow is all about? :) ANd if this was helpful to you, do an upvote or mark it as an answer.

Comment: I was testing using my log in from parse just using a wrong password and it was being processed so quickly that it wasn't appearing. Doh